# how to find minimum difference between average of array and elements in that array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

First of all I need to find average of array, and then I need to find minimum difference between average of array and elements in that array and to display on which place is that element. This is the array:

```
myArray(4,-18,78,136,-52,14,19,-35,162,71,19,-5,-134,77,-78,-35,19);
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: If you want to find the sum you can do that : <?php
$a = array(4,-18,78,136,-52,14,19,-35,162,71,19,-5,-134,77,-78,-35,19);
echo "sum(a) = " . array_sum($a) . "\n";

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I didn't writte well I need the average value of array and the minimum difference between average value and element in that array. I know how to find average value, but don't know how to find minimum difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    <?php

$myArray = array(4,-18,78,136,-52,14,19,-35,162,71,19,-5,-134,77,-78,-35,19);
$averageArray = "";

//Average of the array
if(count($myArray) > 0) {
    $averageArray = array_sum($myArray)  / count($myArray);
}
$diff = array();

//Diff of average value and each value in a array named diff 
if(isset($myArray)) {
    foreach($myArray as $value) {
        $diff[] = abs($averageArray - $value);
    }
}
$key = array_search(min($diff),$diff);
echo "average = " . $averageArray .' - min value :'.min($diff).' - index:'.$key .' value: '.$myArray[$key]."\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have some errors with foreach loop and echo.

Comment: Yes, I have tested now, it should be better !

Comment: Now it works but I think that this is not the right answer or I didn't again explain well what I need to do because my English a little weak. Average of array is this number 14.235294117647(that is OK) but minimum difference is with number 14 in that array.I need to display that number  because smallest difference is with number 14 and its index in array is 5.

Comment: I need to display average of array is: 14.235294117647, minimum difference is with number: 14, and his index or key in thaht array is: 5

Comment: And once again I apologize if I was not clear enough.

Comment: then i have updated my answer

Comment: I advice you update your answer for the others !

Answer (score 0):

Crude but working:

```
<?php
$myArray = [4,-18,78,136,-52,14,19,-35,162,71,19,-5,-134,77,-78,-35,19];

// the average: sum/count
$average = round(array_sum($myArray) / count($myArray));

foreach ($myArray as $value) {
  $diffs[] = abs($average - $value);
}

asort($diffs);
print_r($diffs);
$d = reset($diffs);
$p = array_search($d, $diffs);

echo sprintf("Average: %s, min diff: %s, diff pos: %s\n", $average, $d, $p);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I didn't writte well I need the average value of array and the minimum difference between average value and element in that array. I know how to find average value, but don't know how to find minimum difference between them

Comment: I modified the answer to use the average instead of the sum, the rest stays the same. This does output the element with the minimal difference to the average.

Comment: Made another modification to simplify computation.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to conceptualise an algorithm. What comes to mind is: find the average, find the absolute difference from each element to the average, and then find the minimum. The average can be calculated from the sum and the length.

```
$avg = array_sum($array) / count($array);
$diff = function ($x) use ($avg) { return abs($x - $avg); };
$answer = min(array_map($diff, $array));
```

To also get the element that is closest to the average, instead of mapping to just the difference we can keep the original element along for the ride. Then when we find the minimum we only compare the difference.

```
function minBy(callable $f, array $xs) {
  $min = $xs[0];
  foreach ($xs as $x) {
    if ($f($x, $min) < 0) $min = $x;
  }
  return $min;
}

$avg = array_sum($array) / count($array);
$diff = function ($x) use ($avg) { return array($x, abs($x - $avg)); };
$byDiff = function ($x,$y) { return $x[1] - $y[1]; };
$answer = minBy($byDiff, array_map($diff, $array));
```

To find the index of the element in the array (note that this may not be unique), you can use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).